# swamp cooler high fan is same speed as low

Tags: evaporative-cooling

If I turn it on to high speed, my swamp cooler "turns" but it's the same speed as if it were on "normal."  What gives?

Other clues: when it's on "high" it has very short lived bursts where it blows a little extra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a loose belt.  Once I tightened the belt between motor and pulley (by loosening the motor, pushing it, tightening it up again) then it worked fine.  Even the "low" speed was higher than what the old speed(s) both used to be.